# Degrees of freedom formula

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

I am reading about degrees of freedom and came across the formula

Degrees of freedom = (number of categories) - 1 - (Number of parameters estimated from the data)

I can not get the "Number of parameters estimated from the data" part. What does it mean?

Comment: Degrees of freedom for what? What kind of model you are talking about?

Comment: Also, check out the question [How to understand degrees of freedom?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) as it may cover what you're interested in.